# Recursion of polynomials

Tags: polynomials, recurrence-relations

I have the following equation on the functions $f_i$ for $i>1$, defined in $[0,1/4)$

$$f_i(x) = f_{i-1}(x) + \frac{x}{1-4x}f_{i-2}(x)$$

And assume that $f_0$ equals $c(x)$, the generating function of the Catalan numbers, and $f_1(x)=(c(x)-1)/x$.

Any idea on how can I get a closed form if it exists, or differential equation, or relation to well known polynomials?

Comment: use the power series $S=\sum_{i\ge 0} f_i*t^i$ and the recurrence to solve for $S$.

Comment: I've done that. But what does your function $S(x,t)$ say about the individual $f_i$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Testing the form $f_i = g^i$, we get $g^2 = g + \frac{x}{1-4x} \implies g_{\pm} = \frac12 \pm \frac1{2\sqrt{1-4x}}$

So letting $f_i  =a g_+^i + b g_-^i$, we get $c = a+b$ and 
$$\frac{c-1}x = \frac{a+b}2 + \frac{a-b}{2\sqrt{1-4x}} \implies a - b = \frac{\sqrt{1-4x}}x(2c - 2-x c) $$
From which we should get
$$f_i = \frac12\left(c+ \frac{\sqrt{1-4x}}x(2x-2-xc) \right)\left(\frac12 + \frac1{2\sqrt{1-4x}} \right)^i +  \frac12\left(c - \frac{\sqrt{1-4x}}x(2x-2-xc) \right)\left(\frac12 - \frac1{2\sqrt{1-4x}} \right)^i $$

Assuming the working's all right, does the form help?